# Extend authentication with custom licenses entities?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm using Keycloak as an auth server behind an Nginx reverse proxy.
Leveraging the multi-tenancy and multi-roles suites my needs but I'd like to extend the authentication flow with some custom user-properties that would be ideally stored in an alternative schema/database.

These could be exemplified by:

- A global subscription with an expiration date associated with one or more tenants/realms.
- A license with expiration date associated with each user inside the same tenant/realm.
- ...

From what I've understood I could exploit a custom Authenticator SPI that checks these fields based on the user_id and add it to a custom Authentication Flow defined for each separate client inside my pool. Is this the correct use case or is there a better general approach to apply?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achive. A custom required action like "Purchase license" could work as well.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this or do you have further insights?